# How to play video file from documentdirectory using avplayer

Tags: ios, avplayer

I am creating video player application in ios,if i store mp4 file in bundle resource or if i stream url it is working fine but if i store a file in document direcory and i am trying to play with avplayer it is not playing should i handle differently with offline file in document directory

code:

```
let fileManager = FileManager()
        let destinationURLForFile = URL(fileURLWithPath: documentDirectoryPath.appendingFormat("/myvideo.mp4"))
   self.playVideo(filePath: destinationURLForFile.path)


   func playVideo(filePath:String)
    {
        var playerItem = AVPlayerItem.init(url:URL.init(string: filePath)!)

        var player = AVPlayer(playerItem: playerItem)
        var playerLayer = AVPlayerLayer(player: player)
        playerLayer.frame = self.view.frame
        self.view.layer.addSublayer(playerLayer)
        player.play()

    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

swift 3/4 100%%%%%%% workable

Recorder open video camera

```
@IBAction func RecordAction(_ sender: Any) {

        if UIImagePickerController.isSourceTypeAvailable(UIImagePickerControllerSourceType.camera){
            print("CameraAvailable")
            let imagePicker = UIImagePickerController()
            imagePicker.delegate = self
            imagePicker.sourceType = .camera
            imagePicker.mediaTypes = [kUTTypeMovie as String]
            imagePicker.allowsEditing = false
            imagePicker.showsCameraControls = true

            self.present(imagePicker,animated: true, completion: nil)
        }

        else{
            print("CameraNotAvailable")
        }
    }
```

save to document directory

```
func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [String : Any]) {
        // recover video URL
        let url = info[UIImagePickerControllerMediaURL] as? URL
        // check if video is compatible with album
        let compatible: Bool = UIVideoAtPathIsCompatibleWithSavedPhotosAlbum((url?.path)!)
        // save
        if compatible {
            UISaveVideoAtPathToSavedPhotosAlbum((url?.path)!, self, nil, nil)
            print("saved!!!! \(String(describing: url?.path))")

        }
        videopath = url //save url to send next function play video
        dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
//   error
    func video(_ videoPath: String, didFinishSavingWithError error: Error?, contextInfo: UnsafeMutableRawPointer) {
    }
```

play video from Document directory

```
 @IBAction func playvideo(_ sender: Any)
    {
        let player = AVPlayer(url: videopath!)  // video path coming from above function

        let playerViewController = AVPlayerViewController()
        playerViewController.player = player
        self.present(playerViewController, animated: true) {
            playerViewController.player!.play()
        }
}
```

Answer (score 5):

Try this, written in **Swift 3.0**,

```
let fm = FileManager.default
let docsurl = try! fm.url(for:.documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask, appropriateFor: nil, create: false)
let path = docsurl.appendingPathComponent("myvideo.mp4")
playVideo(filePath: path)

func playVideo(filePath:String)
{
    var playerItem = AVPlayerItem(url: URL(fileURLWithPath: filePath)
    var player = AVPlayer(playerItem: playerItem)
    var playerLayer = AVPlayerLayer(player: player)
    playerLayer.frame = self.view.frame
    self.view.layer.addSublayer(playerLayer)
    player.play()

}
```

Comment: both are same there is no difference

Comment: You missed the line of code to retrieving the Documents path in the question.

Comment: Replce `playVideo(filePath: path)` with `playVideo(filePath: path.path)`

Answer (score 3):

I tried several methods including the above, but found that the documents path changes for the app each time it is launched, which changes the first part of the URL.

This helped me to get the current location of my file:

```
let documentsPath = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(.documentDirectory, .userDomainMask, true)[0]
let playerItem = AVPlayerItem(url: URL(fileURLWithPath: documentsPath.appendingFormat("/\(clipId).mp4")))
player = AVPlayer(playerItem: playerItem)
```

Comment: It workks,This is actually very smart,you have helped me ,thank you i see you have clipId ,i geuss you are making a video app,anyway i am tryina give the help back,do you want a url  that gives you json response with youtube  video url download links,i will you give it you,thank you very much